# Why can you push to an array refrence in JS but not PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I came across this today and would like to know why it does this in terms of how arrays are treated in php and js.

JS

```
let x = [];
let i = x;

i.push('test');
console.log(x);
//prints ['test']
```

PHP

```
$x = [];
$i = $x;

array_push($i, 'test');
print_r($x);
/prints []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well in JavaScript `x` is assigned by reference to `i` while in PHP it is by value. If you want to make it work in PHP you should use:

```
$i = &$x;
```

Which means any changes in `$i` will affect `$x`.  See [PHP: References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

Comment: So in php it makes a copy instead of a refrence? im not sure I understand

Comment: Correct. It takes a copy of $x on the current status

Comment: Ah! i see the difference now. And you answer makes it a refrence instead of a copy. Thanks for the info

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes more but i will do :)